# Controlling the month (beginning and end of each week)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have to show a report for a full month, with multiple columns, the last column corresponds to the hours worked in the week. The code is as follows:

```
    <table>
    <head>
     <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Timer</th>
         <th>Weekly Hours</th>
     </tr>
    </head>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($hours as $i => $time)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $time['WeekDay'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $time['log_date'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $time['total_hours'] }}</td>
            @if(($time['WeekDay'] == "Sunday") || (date('d', strtotime($i)) == count($hours)))
                <td>{{ $time['total_week']) }}</td>
            @endif
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

I want the total hours a week on Sundays only show (final day). It is easy, because with a "IF" I can see if it's Sunday and I show it, but my problem is, if the last day of the month is Thursday and there I show the total hours worked in that week only have 4 days?

this is how the information is displayed now, and I want to show only the data at the end of each week:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if it is the last item in the array?

```
<?php $lastIndex = count($times) - 1; ?>
@foreach ($times as $i => $time)
    @if(isSunday() || $i == $lastIndex)
        {{-- display weekly total --}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Note that this only works if its a *numeric* array

Comment: yes, but, If the last day is Friday, I have to show the total number of days of that week, but I have to assess whether it has complied total hours worked for those 4 days. How do I know that?

Comment: Do you want to show the hours of the full week or the hours of the part of the week that's still in the current month?

Comment: the hours of the part of the week that's still in the current month

Comment: Okay. Do you calculate the weekly total directly in the view or somewhere else?

Comment: in the controller I calculate the total hours a week, and put it in a position of my array (time): "$ time ['total_week']" (everyday keep the cumulative total hours per week)

Comment: Could you please update the question with that code?

Comment: I've already updated, now you can see how it looks, which is not as estimating that the first week instead of working 40 hours, must have worked 24 hours

Comment: I need to see your code that calculates `total_week`